# Metro Apps won't open

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Most of those Metro apps on my Windows 8 computer won't open. It looks like the internal renderer is broken or something like that. Here is some screenshots.

[image]

> This is the store app. The logo and the loading gif is floated toward the left side.

[image]

> This is the Skype app. The logo doesn't even show up.

I have tried the [App Troubleshoot program](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab) but the issue persists.

As far as I know, the so-called Metro Apps uses HTML and JavaScript, which basically is a webpage with an extra command shell. (Bad decision, Microsoft.) Is there a probability that the renderer is broken?

Here's the Weather app:
[image]

Comment: also check the registry permissions: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I digged into the problem, I figured out that it is because JavaScript of IE was turned off by my antivirus. I uninstalled it and now everything is back to normal again.

Comment: I've this problem too.. But I don't have any anti-virus installed. Do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: @AmitJoki Does the render seem broken like the ones I showed?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. I get Remote Procedure Call Failed error.

Comment: @AmitJoki According to this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/most-windows-8-apps-crashing-the-remote-procedure/bd8e99df-ebe3-44bd-ae6d-c698b71f35a2), it seems that this issue is related to graphic card drivers. Try updating them or following the steps described in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the app Trouble shooter,  you should now try playing with the registry  because that worked for me

First Please make sure that the registry and folder permissions are not changed :

Refer  to this link and try to verify all  the permission, they must be same as that in the article given below

Win8: App: Modern: Apps fail to start if default registry or file permissions modified

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317/en-us

**After you have set the permissions right according to the article given above,**

->Run process Monitor while trying to start an app. Now take a  look at  results column list and see if  there are any errors.

->  Now you must add , **ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES to ‪C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Packages with Modify permissions**.

The Apps should work now

let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I have checked everything according to the Windows support page but all the permissions are set correctly.

Comment: Also the process monitor is not really helpful because it is showing everything and I can't filter out only the app.