# Windows 8.1 apps Calculator, Alarms, Weather (just a few) crash immediately when opened

Tags: crash, windows-8.1

When I open some apps from the Start Screen in Windows 8.1, it just closes right away and brings me back to Start.

It won't show me why it closed at all, but I looked in Event Viewer and it says in the description of the event: `Activation of app Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.`

This only started happening recently. It was not right after my Windows 8.1 upgrade, it happened about a week after. I don't remember anything I did differently that could've caused this.

**Update:** There is a more detailed error about what happened in the Event Viewer. It looks like a message from the original process. It's not a `wwahost.exe` process, so there must be a native executable for the Calculator app.

```
Faulting application name: Numbers.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16422, time stamp: 0x5252aa2a
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d4b78
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000a4f30a
Faulting process id: 0x510
Faulting application start time: 0x01ced4f4c2172eb3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_6.3.9600.20278_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Numbers.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 003d791e-40e8-11e3-825f-e89a8fb9d4bb
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_6.3.9600.20278_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

**Update 2:** The Weather app also crashes, and this one runs under `wwahost.exe`. I don't know if this helps anything.

```
Faulting application name: wwahost.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215d0bb
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d557d
Exception code: 0x00000004
Fault offset: 0x000000000000ab78
Faulting process id: 0x5d8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ced4f76d555461
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\wwahost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ab102e6a-40ea-11e3-825f-e89a8fb9d4bb
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.BingWeather_3.0.1.203_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 Metro Apps won't load](http://superuser.com/questions/562188/windows-8-metro-apps-wont-load), [Metro apps crash on startup, driver or permissions issue?](http://superuser.com/questions/432859/metro-apps-crash-on-startup-driver-or-permissions-issue?lq=1), [Metro Apps won't open](http://superuser.com/questions/649433/metro-apps-wont-open?lq=1)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317

Answer (score 0):

One possible way around this is to remove that particular icon from the start screen.  Then go to the desktop, right click the corresponding icon (if available), and hit 'add to start'.  Then this icon will move to the start menu.

It's more of a work-around, but I've had the same problem and this worked for me.  I didn't check the event viewer, however, so yours might be having a different issue.

Comment: Do you mean the desktop Calculator?

Comment: I need to be able to access Alarms and Reading List also.

Comment: You might want to look at this too: [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/most-windows-8-apps-crashing-the-remote-procedure/bd8e99df-ebe3-44bd-ae6d-c698b71f35a2).  Here they talk about updating your graphics driver...

Comment: My graphics driver is already up to date, but I added some info in the question if it helps.